# getting "no rule to make target .s

Tags: assembly, makefile

I know it's been asked before but i couldn't solve the issue.
I'm getting this: No rule to make target 'remww.s', needed by 'remww.o'.  Stop.
This is my Makefile:

```
all: clean $(MAKECMDGOALS)

%:

    echo '(load "project.scm") (compile-scheme-file "$(MAKECMDGOALS).scm"
 "$(MAKECMDGOALS).s")' | scheme -q

$(MAKECMDGOALS).o: $(MAKECMDGOALS).s

    nasm -f elf $(MAKECMDGOALS).s -o $(MAKECMDGOALS).o

$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKECMDGOALS).o

    gcc -m32 -Wall -g $(MAKECMDGOALS).o -o $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    rm -f *.o $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

i tried "make remww", also remww.scm exist in my directory. the scheme program which i echod is running ok and create the remww.s file when i'm running it standalone and manually put the arguments.

Comment: Those empty lines after your target:prerequisite lines aren't there in reality, are they? Otherwise your make should complain with a different error. Can you please edit your example to correctly display the current situation?

Comment: Lots of issues with this makefile...  First, `all: clean $(MAKECMDGOALS)` introduces a race condition.  If you did `make -j xxx.o`, it would build xxx.o at the same time it is calling `rm -f *.o xxx.o`.    Depending on the load on your various processors, it could build xxx.o first, and then rm it right afterwards (which would be a non-obvious failure).   Also @Martin is correct -- get rid of your references to `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, as they're all error prone (consider if there are multiple targets specified...)

Comment: There's one empty line after %:...I'm trying to tell the makefile that $(MAKECMDGOALS).s will be created during the run of the sceme program which i echod. it's not there before this line complete it's evaluation

Comment: Don't invalidate existing answers by adding a new question to the end your post.

Comment: FYI, empty lines are fine.  They look weird to people used to reading "normal" makefiles, but make has no problem with them.

Comment: Using `MAKECMDGOALS` is wrong here.  If you run something like `make foo bar` then the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable will have the value `foo bar`, and your rules will expand to things like `foo bar.o: foo bar.s` which is clearly not right.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I'm not an expert in Makefile syntax but I don't know what the following line should do:

```
%:
```

If you want to tell `make` that the file `$(MAKECMDGOALS).s` can be created from the file `$(MAKECMDGOALS).scm` the line should be replaced by the following line:

```
$(MAKECMDGOALS).s: $(MAKECMDGOALS).scm
```

... and your Makefile should work fine.

I myself would also try to get rid of the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` in most rules. This should be possible the following way, however I'm not 100% sure because this Makefile contains some specialities...:

```
%.s: %.scm
    echo '(load "project.scm") (compile-scheme-file "$<" "$*")' | scheme -q

%.o: %.s

    nasm -f elf $< -o $*

%: %.o

    gcc -m32 -Wall -g $< -o $*
```

Comment: Hey..first of all thanks. i tried what you suggest so i changed the makefile into this: %.s: %.scm
    echo '(load "project.scm") (compile-scheme-file "$<" "$*")' | scheme -q

%.o: %.s

    nasm -f elf $< -o $*

%: %.o

    gcc -m32 -Wall -g $< -o $*